# Cannot restart Ubuntu after replacing Unity with Gnome and purging lightdm

Tags: 11.10, unity, gnome, lightdm

I am running Ubuntu 11.10. I used the directions [here](http://linux-software-news-tutorials.blogspot.com/2011/10/ubuntu-1110-oneiric-remove-unity-and.htmlexit) to replace Unity with Gnome. It seemed to work fine until the end of step 2 when I rebooted the computer. When I chose the default option, I just got a black screen. When I choose the restore option and then "Restore normal boot" I get

```
Starting load fallback graphics devices    [fail]
Starting GNOME Display Manager [ok]
Starting Userspace bootsplash [ok]
Stopping GNOME Display Manager [ok]
Stopping Userspace bootsplash [ok]
Starting web server apach22    [fail]
```

(among a lot of OKs)

It finally gets to Stopping System V runlevel compatibility [ok] where it hangs. I left it overnight and just had a blank screen when I checked it in the morning.

I can "Drop to root shell prompt" and "Drop to root shell prompt with networking". I did see [here](http://linux-software-news-tutorials.blogspot.com/2011/10/ubuntu-1110-oneiric-remove-unity-and.htmlexit) that one should be able to fix the problem by choosing remount and then doing

```
apt-get install lightdm
```

I tried this as root shell with and without networking and got the message

```
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneric-updates/main lightdm i386 1.0.6-0ubuntu1.7
Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu'
```

What is the best way to resolve this problem?

Thanks,
Peter.

Comment: The page you refer to doesn't exist. But you do need networking in order to download things from the web, so try opening a root shell _with_ networking.

Comment: I opened the root shell with networking but I got the same result.  Is there a way to stop it looking for that page or at least looking for a page that exists?  Thanks, Peter

Answer (score 1):

I did some digging around on this site and found that I needed to type

```
dhclient eth0
```

to get Internet connectivity since I had wired Internet connection.  From there it was plain sailing.  Thank you Jcubed!